# Transcribing ASCII values into Images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

So, this is a confusing problem I am not entirely sure I understand. What I have to do is take ASCII values and create grayscale art with them in a .txt file. My two inputs are the picture and the string of letters I have to make....pretty. So this is what my function header entails:

```
Function Name: image2ascii
Inputs  (2): - (char) the file name of an image to analyze
               - (char) a string of characters to use to make ASCII art
 Output Files (1): - a .txt file that resembles the original image
```

I am given a set of guidelines:

```
1) Convert the input image to grayscale by averaging the values of the
      red, blue, and green layers. Do not truncate the values!
   2) For each 8x4 block in the grayscale image, compute the average
      intensity (I) of all 32 pixels and round it to the nearest integer.
   3) Map these values to characters using the following scheme:
        0 <= I <=  31 : input_string(1)
       32 <= I <=  63 : input_string(2)
       64 <= I <=  95 : input_string(3)
       96 <= I <= 127 : input_string(4)
      128 <= I <= 159 : input_string(5)
      160 <= I <= 191 : input_string(6)
      192 <= I <= 223 : input_string(7)
      224 <= I <= 255 : input_string(8)
   4) Print these characters to a .txt file with the same filename as the
      input image. There should be a newline character at the end of each
      line.
```

I did number 1! So I am getting somewhere. I am unsure about the 8x4 block. I was thinking of doing a subplot....
As for number 3....I figured I would do an if statement for those, but I am a little confused. 
Number 4....I will get to that once I understand a little better what to do for everything else.

```
Notes:
   - The input image will always be evenly divisible into 8x4 blocks
   - The input string will always have 8 characters
```

Test case:

```
image2ascii('abe.jpg', '@8XYv:. ');
 => output file named 'abe.txt' identical to 'abe_soln.txt'
```

Ol' Abe : http://tinypic.com/r/wb4g42/8

[image]

I will post the solution at the bottom...because it's huge

This is what I have so far:

```
function image2ascii(pic, str)
%// Reads in the image
Img = imread(pic);
%// Extracts the color layers
Red = Img(:,:,1);
Green = Img(:,:,2);
Blue = Img(:,:,3);
%// Finds the size
[r,c,l] = size(Img);
%// Grayscales the image
gray = uint8((double(Red)+ double(Green)+ double(Blue))./3);
Red = gray;
Green = gray;
Blue = gray;
%// Creates a grayscaled image
Grayimg = cat(3,Red,Green,Blue);

%//Makes it into 8x4 blocks
imgrows = r ./ 8;
imgcols = c ./ 4;

end
```

abe_soln txt:

```
YYvvvvvvvvvvvvYX888XXXXXXX8888888@@@@@8XYvv:::::::::::::::::
vvvvvvvvvvvvX8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Yv::::::::::::::::
vvvvvvvvvvv8@@@@@@@@8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@X:::..:.:::::::::
vvvvvvvvY8@@@@@@8XXX88@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Y::......:::..:.
vvvvvvX@8@@@@@@@8888888@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8XXXXYYvv::.....
vvvvv8@@@@@@@@8888@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8888@@@@@@@@@@88XXYv...
vvvvX@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Xv:::..vX8@@@@@@@8888Xv:.
vvvv@@@@@@@@@@@@@8888@@@@@@@8888XYv:..      .v8@@8888888XYv:
vvv8@@@@@@@@@8Yv::::v:::::::::....          ..vX88XY8@8XYv::
vvv@@@@@@@XY:.....                          ...vXYYX@@@X:...
vvX@@@@@8v.                                ....:vvY88888v...
vY@@@@88v.                               .......vXX88XXXY...
vX@@@88Y.                             .......::.vYX8XX8XY. .
v8@@8XXv...                     .. ..........::::vXYX88X8:  
v@@XXXXv...                              ....::::v8Y8XX888: 
v8888XYv...                              ...:::vvYXXX@8X8@X.
vY8@8YXY:..                             ..:::vvYYYX888@8@@X:
vv8@@X8X:...             .      ..:vvvYYXX88XYvYYYX@@@@@88XX
v8@@@88X::...:vYYYYXXXXYYv:..:::vYX@@@@@@@@@@88XYYX8@@8XXYXX
vY8@8@@Xv:::YXX88@@@@@@@@XXv..vY8@@@@@@8888@@@88YYX8@8YXXYYY
vX@@@@@8Y:.:Y8@@@@@@@@@@8XY: .vv88@@@88888888888XYY888X88YYY
Y@XYY88XY:.vX8@8888@8X@8XX::   .YXXYvv::vvYXYYYYYvvY8@@8XYYY
YXvvvYvYY:.vYY:.:::vvvv::...   .vYvv:::::::::v:::vvY8@@8XYvv
vYvvvY88Y:...........::.        vYYv::vv::::::..:vvX888XXvv:
vv:::Y88Y::.   ........         :vYYv::...:....::vY@@8XYvvv.
vvvv:vX8Yv:..    ....    ..     .vYXv:........:vvY8@@8Yv::: 
vvvvvvv888Y::.......    ..      .vXYYv:....::vYYXX@@@Xvv::  
vvvv:::v88@Xv::::..   .v:  ..::vYXXYYYXv:.:vYXX88@@@8YYv:.  
vvvvv:.::X@@XYYvv:...vYv.:XX888@@@@@XvvYv:vvXXXX88@Yv:..    
vvvvvv:::v@@@XYvvv::vXv   ..:YXY888XYv::vYvYXYXXX88Y:       
vvvvvv:::::X88XYYY:vX:       .v.:YYvvvvvvvYYXYXXXX8Y..      
vvvvvv:::::YXXXXYYvv........::..vvvvvYYXYYYY8YYXXXXv:..     
vvvvvv::::vXXXXYYY::Y8Y:::vvvvvYYYYXXX88XXvY888XX8Xv:.      
vvvvvvv:::YY88XXYYvvXv.:vvvvvvvvYYXX8XYYYvvX888888XXv.      
YYvvvvvvv::YX88X8XXXXYvv:vY88X8X888XXXX8XX88888888vv.       
Yvvvvvvv::::YX8888X8@@8@88v:::vYYYYX8@88@888@88888Y.        
YYYvvvvv:::::Y8@@@@@@888@8XYYYXXXXX88@@8@@@@@@@@XXv.        
YYYvvvvvv::::vX@@@@@@@@@@@8XX888X8@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Yv:.        
YYYvvvvvvv::::v8@@@@@@@@@@@X@@888@@@@@@@@@@@@@Yv:YY.        
YYYvvvvvvvvv:::vY8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8v:.  .@Y.       
YYYYvvvvvvvv:::v v@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Y.    X@@8:      
YYYYvvvvvvv::v8Y Y@8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@XYv::.     Y@@@@@Y.    
YYYYvvvvvvv:Y@@.  :XX8@@@@@@@@@@@@XY:.         :@@@@@@@8v. .
YYYvvvvvvvvX@@X     vYYXYX88@@8Xv..::::..     .@@@@@@@@@@8Yv
YYvvvvvvvv8@@@v               ...:Y8@@@@@@8XYY@@@@@8@@@@@@@@
YYvvvvvvv8@@@@v   :YXXYvvvvvvYX88@@@@@8XXXX8@@@@@@888888888@
YYYYYX8@@@@@@@Y Y@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@88XYYYYYYYY8XYYX8888888888
YYX8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@XXYYXX88XXXXXXYYXvvYYYvY8@XvvX888888888
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@X8@@@8XYYXX88XXXYYYXXYXYvYY8@8XXvY8@@88888888
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Y   vXXXYX8@@@8888XXXXXY88@XYYvvvY@@@@@@888888
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool problem!

Given how much MATLAB knowledge you know so far, we can't use any fancy image processing functions... even though I would love to use them.  We have no choice but to do this with loops.

The first part of what you have is correct.  You read in the image, extract all of the planes, then average all of the planes together.  What you need to do next is open up a file where you're going to write your ASCII art to.  We're going to name this file to be the same as the input image's name.  Once you open up this file, then we need to extract 8 x 4 blocks (distinct), compute the mean intensity and round.  Once we do this, we use the intensity to figure out which character from the input string of characters we need.

We notice that each valid range is a multiple of 32.  Therefore, we simply take our intensity and divide by 32.  This will tell us which index we need to go into.  Note that when you divide by 32, we only need the whole number when dividing, as this will tell us which **multiple** of the range we are in.  As such, you'll need to take the `floor`.  Once you do this, we will get a value from 0 - 7.  To go from 1 - 8, as MATLAB indexes arrays starting at 1, we simply add 1.  We can use this index to index into `index_string` to extract the correct character to write to file.

We use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to print a single character, which is the character from `input_string` into the file.  After each row, we need to put in a manual carriage return to go to the next row.  We repeat this until we reach the last block of your image, and we close the file.

Without further ado:

```
function [] = image2ascii(pic, input_string)

%// Reads in the image
Img = imread(pic);
%// Extracts the color layers
Red = Img(:,:,1);
Green = Img(:,:,2);
Blue = Img(:,:,3);

%// Grayscales the image
gray = uint8((double(Red)+ double(Green)+ double(Blue))/3);

%// Open up a file for reading.  Call it the same as the image name
%// but as a text file
fid = fopen([pic(1:end-4) '.txt'], 'w');

%// For each 8 x 4 block we have
for r = 1 : 8 : size(Img,1)
    for c = 1 : 4 : size(Img,2)

        %// Extract the block
        block = gray(r:r+7,c:c+3);

        %// Find the average intensity and round
        meanBlock = round(mean(block(:)));

        %// Figure out which character to output
        index = floor(meanBlock/32) + 1;        
        fprintf(fid,'%c', input_string(index));
    end
    %// Go to the next row
    fprintf(fid,'\n');
end

%// Close the file
fclose(fid);
```

---

With your example image, this is the output I get from the text file:

```
YYvvvvvvvvvvvvYX888XXXXXXX8888888@@@@@8XYvv:::::::::::::::::
vvvvvvvvvvvvX8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Yv::::::::::::::::
vvvvvvvvvvv8@@@@@@@@8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@X:::..:.:::::::::
vvvvvvvvY8@@@@@@8XXX88@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Y::......:::..:.
vvvvvvX@8@@@@@@@8888888@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8XXXXYYvv::.....
vvvvv8@@@@@@@@8888@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8888@@@@@@@@@@88XXYv...
vvvvX@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Xv:::..vX8@@@@@@@8888Xv:.
vvvv@@@@@@@@@@@@@8888@@@@@@@8888XYv:..      .v8@@8888888XYv:
vvv8@@@@@@@@@8Yv::::v:::::::::....          ..vX88XY8@8XYv::
vvv@@@@@@@XY:.....                          ...vXYYX@@@X:...
vvX@@@@@8v.                                ....:vvY88888v...
vY@@@@88v.                               .......vXX88XXXY...
vX@@@88Y.                             .......::.vYX8XX8XY. .
v8@@8XXv...                     .. ..........::::vXYX88X8:  
v@@XXXXv...                              ....::::v8Y8XX888: 
v8888XYv...                              ...:::vvYXXX@8X8@X.
vY8@8YXY:..                             ..:::vvYYYX888@8@@X:
vv8@@X8X:...             .      ..:vvvYYXX88XYvYYYX@@@@@88XX
v8@@@88X::...:vYYYYXXXXYYv:..:::vYX@@@@@@@@@@88XYYX8@@8XXYXX
vY8@8@@Xv:::YXX88@@@@@@@@XXv..vY8@@@@@@8888@@@88YYX8@8YXXYYY
vX@@@@@8Y:.:Y8@@@@@@@@@@8XY: .vv88@@@88888888888XYY888X88YYY
Y@XYY88XY:.vX8@8888@8X@8XX::   .YXXYvv::vvYXYYYYYvvY8@@8XYYY
YXvvvYvYY:.vYY:.:::vvvv::...   .vYvv:::::::::v:::vvY8@@8XYvv
vYvvvY88Y:...........::.        vYYv::vv::::::..:vvX888XXvv:
vv:::Y88Y::.   ........         :vYYv::...:....::vY@@8XYvvv.
vvvv:vX8Yv:..    ....    ..     .vYXv:........:vvY8@@8Yv::: 
vvvvvvv888Y::.......    ..      .vXYYv:....::vYYXX@@@Xvv::  
vvvv:::v88@Xv::::..   .v:  ..::vYXXYYYXv:.:vYXX88@@@8YYv:.  
vvvvv:.::X@@XYYvv:...vYv.:XX888@@@@@XvvYv:vvXXXX88@Yv:..    
vvvvvv:::v@@@XYvvv::vXv   ..:YXY888XYv::vYvYXYXXX88Y:       
vvvvvv:::::X88XYYY:vX:       .v.:YYvvvvvvvYYXYXXXX8Y..      
vvvvvv:::::YXXXXYYvv........::..vvvvvYYXYYYY8YYXXXXv:..     
vvvvvv::::vXXXXYYY::Y8Y:::vvvvvYYYYXXX88XXvY888XX8Xv:.      
vvvvvvv:::YY88XXYYvvXv.:vvvvvvvvYYXX8XYYYvvX888888XXv.      
YYvvvvvvv::YX88X8XXXXYvv:vY88X8X888XXXX8XX88888888vv.       
Yvvvvvvv::::YX8888X8@@8@88v:::vYYYYX8@88@888@88888Y.        
YYYvvvvv:::::Y8@@@@@@888@8XYYYXXXXX88@@8@@@@@@@@XXv.        
YYYvvvvvv::::vX@@@@@@@@@@@8XX888X8@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Yv:.        
YYYvvvvvvv::::v8@@@@@@@@@@@X@@888@@@@@@@@@@@@@Yv:YY.        
YYYvvvvvvvvv:::vY8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8v:.  .@Y.       
YYYYvvvvvvvv:::v v@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@8Y.    X@@8:      
YYYYvvvvvvv::v8Y Y@8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@XYv::.     Y@@@@@Y.    
YYYYvvvvvvv:Y@@.  :XX8@@@@@@@@@@@@XY:.         :@@@@@@@8v. .
YYYvvvvvvvvX@@X     vYYXYX88@@8Xv..::::..     .@@@@@@@@@@8Yv
YYvvvvvvvv8@@@v               ...:Y8@@@@@@8XYY@@@@@8@@@@@@@@
YYvvvvvvv8@@@@v   :YXXYvvvvvvYX88@@@@@8XXXX8@@@@@@888888888@
YYYYYX8@@@@@@@Y Y@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@88XYYYYYYYY8XYYX8888888888
YYX8@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@XXYYXX88XXXXXXYYXvvYYYvY8@XvvX888888888
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@X8@@@8XYYXX88XXXYYYXXYXYvYY8@8XXvY8@@88888888
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Y   vXXXYX8@@@8888XXXXXY88@XYYvvvY@@@@@@888888
```